# How do I change the Windows Shell for only one User?

Tags: shell, windows-registry

I tried using the [tutorial listed here](http://users.iafrica.com/e/ez/eze/e000002.html) and it should have worked, but it didn't. I checked my spelling, my registry paths, and my values three times, and I followed every step correctly but it didn't work. For some reason it's still going to the key located in HKLM (Local Machine) instead of HKCU (Current User) even though I changed the shell value located in `Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\IniFileMapping\system.ini\boot`to `USR:Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`

It doesn't make any sense why it isn't working.

**Note:** I'm trying to remove the shell completely for one user on the computer but no one else. Also, I did make sure I was logged onto the right user when I changed the shell value in HKCU.

I'm using Windows XP SP3

Comment: So … are you using Windows NT version 4?

Comment: Since that article is from 1998, and it's about Windows NT v4, are you sure it still works under newer Windows versions?  What version of Windows are you trying to apply this to?  What do you mean by "It doesn't work"?  What does it do when you change those settings? What did you set your HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon to?

Comment: I'm using Windows XP SP3 and I can't find a newer article

Comment: Besides, look at http://www.knowledgesutra.com/discuss/ttomsl-change-windows-shell.om, this one was written for XP and it uses the same Key

Comment: What shell are you trying to use? What is your ultimate goal? If you just don't want the explorer interface there are plenty of options, like geoshell, sharpe, Aston, litestep, etc. If you want to use something other than cmd.exe, you can try Tccle and console2. Please be more specific with what you want.

Comment: No, I want no shell at all. I'm trying to make the computer so when you start it up, it opens Internet Explorer in kiosk mode with no shell so they can't do anything else but use internet explorer. That is what was requested by my employer

Comment: I found this link for windows XP, though I have never tried this myself, maybe it will help: http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/DF357CDA59091AE6862576CF005EE86B --- I also found this method as well: http://serverfault.com/questions/18879/how-to-lock-down-windows-xp-for-use-as-an-internet-kiosk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is restart the computer after changing the shell value in HKCU.